# Celery correct chain of groups of tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have a list of lists of strings, which are filenames:

```
chunks_list = [["file_1", "file_2"], ["file_3", "file_4", "file_5"], ...]
```

I need to process this files in celery tasks, so I have task which does it:

```
@celery_app.task
def process_file_task(filename):
    # do some staff with file 
    # (e.g. produce data to Kafka)
```

An I need to **run inner list of files parallel**. And **outer lists should be sequential**.

The way of processing should be next:

```
worker1: file_1
worker2: file_2
```

The next group starts after the first is finished:

```
worker1: file_3
worker2: file_4
worker3: file_5
```

I tried to run my tasks in this way:

```
sequence_tasks = []
for chunks in chunks_list:
    sequence_tasks.append(
        group([process_file_task.si(filename) for filename in chunks])
    )

tasks_chain = chain(
    tasks_group for tasks_group in sequence_tasks
)()
tasks_chain.get()
```

The problem is that I could have thousands of files. And this way of running tasks consumes all my free memory, even if there are only hundred of them.
Please tell me how to design my workflow in correct way to not to get out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the setup details:

- Where are your workers running? docker? (k8s/ecs/..) ec2?
- What's the worker [concurrency](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#concurrency)?
- Is that a must that every file's task (within the same group) will run on a separate worker?

There's always an upper-case - limit of how many workers you have.
Let's say you have 10 workers, each worker with concurrency 1 and 1,000 tasks in a group. They will run almost in parallel (because you don't have 1,000 workers, only 10) but that's fine. Celery will ensure that none of the tasks from the second group will start until it finishes all those first 1,000. If the time it takes to run each task is equal, every worker will handle 100 tasks and then will move on to the next chunk. If the time it takes is different, Celery will optimize by assigning the next tasks to the next free worker.

In other words, you know what the setup is (let's say EC2 instance with 16GB and 8 cores). You also know (I hope) what's the maximum memory size a single task can take. If an average task takes 1GB RAM, you can run at most 16 tasks with parallelism 1 or 6 tasks with parallelism 2 etc.)

Comment: I really forgot to mention my setup. We run it in k8s, where the memory limit of worker pod is set to 5GB. When RAM usage gets to this point it's been killed by SIGKILL.
Then I tried to monitor it's behaviour locally. I have 8 cores and 8 workers. THe problem is that after it calls `tasks_chain.get()` only one python process starts to consume all free memory (up to 16 GB). It seem to me that I do something wrong when I generate groups of tasks in for loop.

Comment: Wait, what about `tasks_chain.delay()` (before get) to trigger the work? What's the return value of each task? Maybe it takes a lot.. (what's your Celery backend by the way)

Comment: `tasks_chain.delay()` did not change anything. One process still takes all free memory before even starting any task.
Return value of tasks in None, it reads the file and produces data to Kafka.
I use Redis both for broker and result backend

Comment: can you try to limit/decrease the canvas that you're building there? (let say, max chunk size 10, total chunks 5) just to mitigate the problem

Comment: @SagitKhaliullin did it help you to solve your problem?

Comment: yes, I will share the solution later when I will test it on really huge amount of files

Comment: @SagitKhaliullin glad to hear! I appreciate if you accept my answer/upvote if it helped you ;)